# What's wrong with this question of mine?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this matching Q&A a couple of days ago](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/784/what-happened-to-dshot1200-support-in-betaflight) and it has since achieved a -1 (*+1, -2*) question score, while the answer has +2 (*+2, -0*). My question is: what's wrong with that question? It reads:

> I just went to update my flight controller from 3.5.3 to 4.1.0, and I noticed that some time in the past two years the option to enable DSHOT1200 was removed from Betaflight.
>
> Does anyone know why this happened?

I don't see anything wrong with it which would warrant disapproval. Could someone help me come to my senses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the question either... and honestly I really wouldn't worry about it that much.  It is short and not extremely detailed, though in my opinion plenty detailed for the subject it covers - but that could be enough to make someone hit the downvote as they drive by.

Really, a couple downvotes doesn't mean much...  If you see a consistent pattern that a particular type of question is being downvoted or that a lot of your questiosn are being downvoted then I'd start being concerned.  But your positive record on the site shows that you're not the kind of user who is spewing out a lot of downvoteable material.

My guess is [Tim Post lost his keys again.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/333472)

Comment: Yes, of course. I felt like this situation might be one to spawn a discussion because votes in the private beta can be signals that this kind of Q/A isn't what the community wants.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the downvoters, to be honest I have got no idea why I downvoted. It's a good question, I have now retracted my vote and upvoted. Apologies.